# Does anyone know what type of tree this is?

Tags: identification, trees

This is one of many trees that are growing in a very shaded area in my new yard in Northern Indiana, United States. They range from about to 2 - 8 feet in height.They have thin branches with big leaves than range from about 6-12 inches long and about 4-5 inches wide.

[image][image]

Comment: Where in the world?

Comment: Northern Indiana

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a native American tree called a Paw Paw (*Asimina triloba*).  They are fruit trees when mature, but are finicky (will not self pollinate) and don't always produce fruit.  They need to be cross pollinated by other unrelated trees of the same species.  Sounds like they are good to eat.  Here are two links that may be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba

https://rockbridgetrees.com/paw-paw-trees/